# Mi codigo no compila, dice que no reconoce el get() set() y begin()

Tags: c++, arduino, get, set, begin-cbegin

¿Me pueden ayudar?
Dice que no reconoce el `get`, `set` y `begin`.
No sé si es un error de la librería.
Quiero mandar los datos a un hosting de firebase.

Este es un error que me aparece

> Compilation error: 'class MAX30105' has no member named 'getHeartRate'

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30105.h"
#include <heartRate.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>

// Provide the token generation process info.
#include "addons/TokenHelper.h"
// Provide the RTDB payload printing info and other helper functions.
#include "addons/RTDBHelper.h"

// Insert your network credentials
#define WIFI_SSID "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SSID"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD"

// Insert Firebase project API Key
#define API_KEY "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PROJECT_API_KEY"

// Insert Authorized Email and Corresponding Password
#define USER_EMAIL "REPLACE_WITH_THE_USER_EMAIL"
#define USER_PASSWORD "REPLACE_WITH_THE_USER_PASSWORD"

// Insert RTDB URLefine the RTDB URL
#define DATABASE_URL "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_DATABASE_URL"

// Define Firebase objects
FirebaseData fbdo;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

// Variable to save USER UID
String uid;

// Variables to save database paths
String databasePath;
String pulsePath;
String oxygenPath;

// MAX30102 sensor
MAX30105 particleSensor;

// Timer variables (send new readings every three minutes)
unsigned long sendDataPrevMillis = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

// Initialize MAX30102 sensor
void initMAX30102()
{
    if (!particleSensor.begin(Wire, I2C_SPEED_FAST))
    {
        Serial.println("MAX30102 was not found. Please check wiring/power.");
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    particleSensor.setup();
    particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeRed(0x0A); //Configure red LED
    particleSensor.setPulseAmplitudeGreen(0);  //Turn off Green LED
}

// Initialize WiFi
void initWiFi()
{
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
    Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        Serial.print('.');
        delay(1000);
    }
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println();
}

// Write float values to the database
void sendFloat(String path, float value)
{
    if (Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, path.c_str(), value))
    {
        Serial.print("Writing value: ");
        Serial.print(value);
        Serial.print(" on the following path: ");
        Serial.println(path);
        Serial.println("PASSED");
        Serial.println("PATH: " + fbdo.dataPath());
        Serial.println("TYPE: " + fbdo.dataType());
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        Serial.println("REASON: " + fbdo.errorReason());
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Initialize MAX30102 sensor
    initMAX30102();
    initWiFi();

    // Assign the api key (required)
    config.api_key = API_KEY;

    // Assign the user sign in credentials
    auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
    auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

    // Assign the RTDB URL (required)
    config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

    Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
    fbdo.setResponseSize(4096);

    // Assign the callback function for the long running token generation task */
    config.token_status_callback = tokenStatusCallback; //see
    addons / TokenHelper.h

                 // Assign the maximum retry of token generation
                 config.max_token_generation_retry = 5;

    // Initialize the library with the Firebase authen and config
    Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);

    // Getting the user UID might take a few seconds
    Serial.println("Getting User UID");
    while ((auth.token.uid) == "")
    {
        Serial.print('.');
        delay(1000);
    }
    // Print user UID
    uid = auth.token.uid.c_str();
    Serial.print("User UID: ");
    Serial.println(uid);

    // Update database path
    databasePath = "/UsersData/" + uid;

    // Update database path for sensor readings
    pulsePath = databasePath + "/pulse";   // --> UsersData/<user_uid>/pulse
    oxygenPath = databasePath + "/oxygen"; // --> UsersData/<user_uid>/oxygen
}

void loop()
{
    // Send new readings to database
    if (Firebase.ready() && (millis() - sendDataPrevMillis > timerDelay || sendDataPrevMillis == 0))
    {
        sendDataPrevMillis = millis();

        // Get latest sensor readings
        float pulse = particleSensor.getHeartRate();
        float oxygen = particleSensor.getSpO2();

        // Send readings to database:
        sendFloat(pulsePath, pulse);
        sendFloat(oxygenPath, oxygen);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál librería estás usando? ¿Esta https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MAX3010x_Sensor_Library? Si miras el código, no tiene ninguna función `getHeartRate`.

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MAX3010x_Sensor_Library/blob/master/examples%2FExample5_HeartRate%2FExample5_HeartRate.ino

Comment: De la documentación: Sensor is capable of detecting pulses but only limited algorithms are provided. It is up to the user to create the algorithms to detect different particles and/or SPO2 and/or do Pulse Detection. O sea, tu tienes que escribir el código para calcular el pulso.